How do I convert master-slave to multimaster database replication in MySQL?
Currently, I have one master and two slaves in my setup. How can I convert it so that I have three masters instead? I need all three nodes to be writable and to update each other accordingly.
Most of the tutorials I find are setting up multimaster from scratch. I cant find one where it converts it to multimaster from master-slave. Thank you.
Edit: I forgot to mention, the 2 new masters should only replicate one specific table from the original master.
